# Is it possible to only output the "title" of a JSON file without it outputting the content of it?

Tags: javascript, html, json

Let's say I have this code:

```
const names = `

    {
         "Joe": {
              "nat": "American",
              "hair": "brown"
         },
         "Peter": {
              "nat": "German",
              "hair": "blond"
         }
    }
`;

const load = JSON.parse(names);
```

Is there a way I can console.log() only (for example) "Joe" without it also outputting the "nat" and "hair"?

Comment: see [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: What do you want the output to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys()` which returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property names

```js
const names = `

    {
         "Joe": {
              "nat": "American",
              "hair": "brown"
         },
         "Peter": {
              "nat": "German",
              "hair": "blond"
         }
    }
`;

const load = JSON.parse(names);

console.log(Object.keys(load)[0]);
```

More about `Object.keys` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: tysm this really helps :D

Comment: You're welcome. i would appreciate if you can accept the answer and vote up my friend (: